# Meaning of "look about you: know you any here?" in "All's Well That Ends Well"

Tags: meaning, william-shakespeare, alls-well-that-ends-well

Shakespeare's *All's Well That Ends Well*, Act IV, Scene 3, contains the following line ([Online Shakespeare, line 2390](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=allswell&Act=4&Scene=3&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=2389#2389)):

> so, look about you: know you any here?

What is the meaning of these words?

Answer (score 1):

Parolles was blindfolded while he was being questioned by noblemen and soldiers who belonged to the same camp as himself. Just before the words "so, look about you: know you any here?", one of these lords removes the blindfold.

The words mean: "Look around you. Do you know any of the people here?"

Parolles then recognises the people around him, including Bertram, and understands he has been fooled into confessing things that he would rather have kept to himself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!